# Why are terminating digits forbidden in module names?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I've created a Java project with the name `java9` to play with Java 9 modules. I have the following `module-info.java`:

```
module java9 {
    ...
}
```

However the javac compiler complains about the digit in my module name:

```
src\module-info.java:1: warning: [module] module name java9 should avoid terminal digits
module java9 {
       ^
```

And at runtime java complains too:

```
WARNING: Module name "java9" may soon be illegal
```

Can anyone explain why terminating digits are forbidden?
What are libraries like `commons-lang3` supposed to do to avoid this restriction?
What if I have a library name like `base64` or `sha3`?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849311/how-to-resolve-module-info-java-compile-error-in-jdk9-java-9) does not contain an answer to my question. It answers how to avoid the error but not why Java is so restrictive in the naming scheme.

Comment: Check out this earlier question: [How to resolve module-info.java compile error in Jdk9/java-9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849311/how-to-resolve-module-info-java-compile-error-in-jdk9-java-9). There's [discussion about the topic](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/issues/#VersionsInModuleNames) in the Jigsaw issues.

Comment: *"why Java is so restrictive in the naming scheme"* It's just a warning, not a restriction.

Comment: *"This question does not contain an answer to my question. It answers how to avoid the error but not why Java is so restrictive in the naming scheme."* - Incorrect.  Read this Answer!  http://stackoverflow.com/a/41859239/139985

Comment: @StephenC And why do they discourage people from encoding versions in module names? This is the question.

Comment: Erm .. it is not the question that you asked.

Comment: @StephenC Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: I said >>they<< think it is a bad idea.